# React Filtering Divs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have problem with filtering divs in React based on clicked buttons. I tried to implement https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_elements in my code but unsuccessfully. Has anyone idea how to modify this? Or some other solution to this, not by switching classes.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Work.css';

class Work extends Component {
    filterSelection = (c) => {
        var x, i;
        x = document.getElementsByClassName("element");
        if (c == "all") c = "";
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            this.w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
            if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) this.w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
        }
    }

    w3AddClass = (element, name) => {
        var i, arr1, arr2;
        arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
        arr2 = name.split(" ");
        for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
            if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {element.className += " " + arr2[i];}
        }
    }

    w3RemoveClass = (element, name) => {
        var i, arr1, arr2;
        arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
        arr2 = name.split(" ");
        for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
            while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
                arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);     
            }
        }
        element.className = arr1.join(" ");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className="container-fluid WorkWrapper">
                    <div className="container">
                    <h1>Work</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="Works">
                        <div className="FilteredView">
                            <button onClick={this.filterSelection("all")}>ALL</button>
                            <span className="slash">&#47;</span>
                            <button onClick={this.filterSelection("print")}>PRINT</button>
                            <span className="slash">&#47;</span>
                            <button onClick={this.filterSelection("photography")}>PHOTOGRAPHY</button>
                            <span className="slash">&#47;</span>
                            <button onClick={this.filterSelection("web")}>WEB</button>
                            <span className="slash">&#47;</span>
                            <button onClick={this.filterSelection("applications")}>APPLICATIONS</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="container">
                    <ul className={"Preview" + (this.state.list ? ' List' : '')}>
                        <a href="https://www.google.com/">
                            <li>
                                <img className="element web" src={WorkGiraffe} alt="Giraffes"/>
                            </li>
                        </a>
                        <a href="https://www.google.com/">
                            <li>
                                <img className="element applications" src={WorkButtons} alt="Buttons"/>
                            </li>
                        </a>
                        <a href="https://www.google.com/">
                            <li>
                                <img className="element photography" src={WorkSliding} alt="Sliding"/>
                            </li>
                        </a>
                        <a href="https://www.google.com/">
                            <li>
                                <img className="element web" src={WorkSmiling} alt="Smiling"/>
                            </li>
                        </a>
                        <a href="https://www.google.com/">
                            <li>
                                <img className="element print" src={WorkSocialMedia} alt="Social Media"/>
                            </li>
                        </a>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default Work;
```

My css file contains:

```
.Preview a li img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.show {
    display: block!important;
}

.element {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: You have forgotten the last part Javascript that add the eventlistener to the buttons.

Comment: No you have event listeners as: **onClick={this.filterSelection("print")}** etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to avoid following that tutorial too much if you are looking to implement it in React, as the 'React' way of doing it using state, is somewhat different.

I've provided a very minimal (by no means perfect) alternative way of doing it, but you'll get the idea.

https://codesandbox.io/s/9090v4w5o

Comment: Have followed your guides, works perfectly, React is so beautiful :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are invoking the event listener as you are rendering it, not on click.

Here is what you have:

```
filterSelection = (c) => {
   ...
}
```

Because you are calling `onClick=this.filterSelection('text')`, you are already invoking the callback.  What you need to do is change `filterSelection` to be the following:

```
filterSelection = (c) => () => {
   ...
}
```

That way it won't run until you've actually clicked on something.

Does that make sense?  Try it.  I did here: https://codesandbox.io/s/lxzpk4p68z